# Docker mount local drive to container

Tags: python, docker, mount

Below it is my docker-compose, now i can build the container, but I cannot load the file in Datasets into the application, the error says that it cannot find the file specified

```
version: '3.8'
services:
  finder-intelligence:
    build: .
    image: finder_ai:latest
    volumes:
      - type: bind
        source: mydata
        target: /mnt/Datasets
        volume:
          nocopy: false
volumes:
  mydata:
    driver: local
    driver_opts:
      o: bind
      type: none
      device: /mnt/Datasets
```

Comment: I don't think the long `volumes: { type: bind }` works with the named volume as you've shown.  Can you use the short form `volumes: [/mnt/Datasets:/mnt/Datasets]`?

Comment: i tried that as well with no success

Comment: $ docker container ls
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE         COMMAND   CREATED              STATUS              PORTS     NAMES
f4480c73585a   prostate_ai   "bash"    About a minute ago   Up About a minute             sleepy_wescoff
$ docker inspect sleepy_wescoff | grep -C2 Binds
        "ExecIDs": null,
        "HostConfig": {
            "Binds": null,
            "ContainerIDFile": "",
            "LogConfig": {

Comment: $ docker ps -q | xargs docker container inspect -f '{{ .Name }} {{ .HostConfig.Binds }}'
/reverent_thompson []

Answer (score 0):

Try to just pass it as:

```
volumes:
      - /host/path/to/share:/container/path/to/share
```

Answer (score 0):

in the end the compose file was fine, my mistake, due to inexperience, i was running docker run instead of docker-compose run